# Meaningful string limiting

Tags: sql, vb.net, string, text

I've got rows in my table that contain text anywhere between 31 character and 281 characters long.

Rather than display all this text in my table on my webpage, I'd like to limit this text to a few characters long so as to identify it to the user.

What I've done is `select left(ColumnName, 30)` but this way is fairly ugly on the page as it cuts off the text in the middle of words.
Can anyone suggest a way to break it on a  character or something that would display better on my page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code:

```
declare @columnname nvarchar(281)
set @columnname = 'Rather than display all this text in my table on my webpage, I''d like to limit this text to a few characters long so as to identify it to the user.'

select case when charindex(' ', @columnname, 30) > 30 
  then left(@columnname, charindex(' ', @columnname, 30)) else @columnname end
```

Result:

```
Rather than display all this text
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see I'll be using charindex() a lot in future, +1 and answer

Comment: @LoganYoung Thanks for the point, I made an important change that you should include so you do not lose data.

Answer (score 1):

One way to handle it would be to modify your existing solution with the `CHARINDEX` function, as below:

```
select left(ColumnName, charindex(' ', ColumnName, 30) - 1)
from TableName
```

This will find the first space starting at position 30, and return everything to the left of that.

For more, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx

Comment: Thanks, +1 but t-clausen.dk posted first, so he gets answer

Comment: I tried that first, imagine the columnname only contains 20 characters. That would cause it to return blank result

Comment: If the columnname only contained 20 characters, you'd probably want to adjust your limit anyway, though.